# Laravel 5.3 - Blank Screen - Insert Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I Newly Installed Laravel 5.3. I Create Model and Controller for Role table. When i send Insert Data to Role Controller. It will be display Blank Page. but print a posted will be display. Select Query will be working but insert query not working.

Controller :

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Role;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.userlist');
    }

     public function roleindex()
    {
        return view('admin.role');
    }

    public function saveRole(request $request)
    {
    $id=Auth::user()->id;
        $role=new Role;
        $role->role_title=$request->input('role');
        $role->created_by=$id;
        $role->created_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $role->save();
       $request->session()->flash('alert-success','Role details  Saved Successfully!');
        return redirect('dddddd');
    }
}
```

Comment: `request ` should be uppervcase

Comment: That's Not Working... @Ohgodwhy

Answer (score 0):

Change your saveRole function as follows.

```
public function saveRole(Request $request)
{ // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: That's Not Working... @Ashan77

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

if this will not work then there will be other issue somewhere else.

```
public function saveRole(\Request $request)
{ 
        $role=new Role;
        $role->role_title=$request->get('role');
        $role->created_by=$id;
        $role->created_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
       $role->save();
       $request->session()->flash('alert-success','Role details  Saved Successfully!');
        return redirect('to_some_url');
}
```